# Display list of the last modified or updated posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Currently I have this wordpress code to show a list of the last modified or updated posts, the problem is that I have a contact form plugin, when someone sends a message through the form it is automatically shown in the list of the last modified posts .

Any way to only allow showing posts, pages and custom post type and exclude that?

This is my code:

```
    <?php
     $today = current_time('mysql', 1);
     $count = 8;
     if ( $recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC LIMIT $count")):
?>
```

Comment: Which form plugin that you currently used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a `post_type` filter on your query,

should be something like

```
SELECT ID, post_title 
FROM $wpdb->posts 
WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_modified_gmt < '$today' 
AND post_type  = 'post' // or if you want to query both post and page just do -> AND post_type IN ('post', 'page')
ORDER BY post_modified_gmt 
DESC 
LIMIT $count
```

Comment: Thank you so much @silver I applied your modification and it has worked correctly. I am very grateful.